# How to detect a player holding a certain block in Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a "Spectator Machine" and I need help with **detecting if a player is holding a redstone block** to return back to their original spot, **Im in Minecraft Bedrock** and I still don't know if I should use /testfor or /execute and I don't know which one works.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this would require an NBT check, like in MCJava, so it would be impossible in MCPE. But who knows, maybe they have some other feature for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to detect what block a player is holding unlike tools,  what you could do instead is use tags.